# process.env.NODE_ENV is undefined in my server file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

do I have to set the process.env.NODE_ENV myself when I am in development? Does node not set the .env to production when I have a build folder, and development when I am in local environment? I was under the impression many libraries use this as a optimization tool

for example in my app.js file the console.log code turns up undefined

```
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
```

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const postsRouter = require('./routes/Post_Route');
const path = require("path")


// parse body on every request //
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

//Routes
app.use('/api/posts', postsRouter);



// Serve up static assets (usually on heroku)
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));
    }

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {

    console.log(`Mongoose is in  production === ${process.env.NODE_ENV}  mongo uri is ${process.env.MONGO_URI_PROD}`)
    // connect DB
```

when I set the NODE.ENV in my .env file I see it as development, am I to set it manually in development then on heroku for example set the NODE_ENV as production?

Answer (score 1):

in package.json

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=production node ./app"
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly enough yes. There is no command like "node script.js --production". Instead, just run this on Linux systems `export NODE_ENV=production` and that will set you. Alternatively, you can change your launch command to `NODE_ENV=production node script.js` and that'll set you right for production testing.

Answer (score 1):

`NODE_ENV=production node script.js` should work.

But it does not work on Windows. So I recommend to use a package like [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) to make it works in all platform.

```
{
  "scripts: {
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node script.js"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the environment variable in server. if you are using linux, check with printenv . if variable not in list you need to define

Answer (score 0):

you can also set it in your webpack config with DefinePlugin. Works on Windows too

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"production"',
    }),
  ],
```

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion I would say `npm install dotenv`

Docs at : https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

then import it within your entry script file 
`import dotenv from "dotenv"`
and as early as possible envoke `dotenv.config()` this will load all variables in your `.env` file.